# Are there in pure mathematics ensembles of number's which not divided by them self except $0$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, divisibility, axioms

In pure mathematics we know well that each number divided by him self except $0$ , the question that let me confused is: Is there a proof  in pure mathematics show to us that there are others ensembles of number's that's don't divide them self .

-in other way, how we could proof that only the number : "0" that's doesn't divide him self ?

I would be interest for any replies or any comment's .Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, what is a 'number'?

Though among complex numbers indeed only $0$ is the only one that cannot be a divisor, if instead of an imaginary number $i$ whose square is $-1$, we extend $\Bbb R$ the same way by an 'imaginary number' $E$ whose square is $1$, then $(1+E)(1-E)=0$,  hence if we had $(1-E)/(1-E)$, then 
$$1+E \ =\ \frac{(1+E)\cdot(1-E)}{1-E}\ = 0\,.$$

This shows that you cannot find a very general proof.

Anyway, the problem is rather with *dividing by $0$* than only $0/0$.

A set equipped with operations (satisfying similar rules as) $+\ -\ \cdot$ is called a *ring*, and a nonzero element $x$ of a ring is called **zero divisor** if $xy=0$ for some nonzero $y$.

If $x$ is a zero divisor in a ring (with $xy=0$), then we cannot have $x/x$, as $y\ne 0$ but
$$y=\frac{x\cdot y}x=\frac0x=0\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $a/b$ is the unique solution of the equation $x\cdot b=a$. That is, if there is no solution or if the solution is not unique, we do not have a quotient. That being said, how can anything not be divisible by itself? How can $x\cdot a=a$ not have $1$ as the unique solution?

Firstly, $1$ could fail to be a solution if there is no $1$ in our number system; for example if we for some reason should decide to work only with even integers then divisions like $24/6=4$ are fine, but neither $24/8$ nor $6/6$ are defined because there is no suitable even integer that could work as quotient. Well, this might suggest tha we should revise our weird decision to ignore odd numbers ...

More importantly, the solution could fail to be unique: $x\cdot a=a$ is equivalent to $(x-1)\cdot a=0$. In rationl, real, complex numbers, a product is zero if and only if at least one of the factors is zero. Thus if $a\ne0$, then necessarily $x-1=0$, i.e. the solution $x=1$ is unique. But if $a=0$, then $x-1$ (and $x$) an be arbitrary.
There are other "number systems" (or better: unitary rings) where such problems may occur even if $a\ne 0$. They have so-callled divisors of zero. As an example take the set of $2\times 2$ matrices with real number entries. Under addition and matrix multiplication they form a ring with the identity matrix $E$ as "one". Whenever $A$ has determinant $0$, there are several $C$ with $CA=0$, and each such $C$ gives rise to a solution $X=C+E$ of $XA=A$ - no unique quotient $A/A$ can be defined.

Answer (score 0):

No. All numbers, real or complex, are divisible by themselves... the sole exception being zero.

Someone might suggest that infinity is another, but infinity is not considered a number... at least not a real number.

There are of course types of mathematics that dont involve numbers at all, and operations on them can be defined rather trickily. Vectors, matrices, etc., and other non-numeric entities. Even some treatments of infinity.  The resolution to your question might rest with these higher, more abstract notions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i want a general proof for this, it's seems as axiom , but always in mathematics we need a preuve

Comment: As you point out, it could axiomatic. I dont know that it is or not, but axioms do not require proofs. Neither do definitions, regardless of their arbitrariness.

Comment: could you convice someone that 1+1 =2 in fondation that's axiom ?

Comment: Im sure your "proof" stems from the definition of division.  $a/b=c$ implies $a = bc$.  When $a=b=0$ the right equation holds for all $c$, but the left is ambiguous. Indeterminate is the name. When we employ 0, the contradictions and inconsistencies happen.

Comment: As far as proving 1+1=2, youre getting into pretty abstract, but the extreme foundations of math... supported only by logic, axiom, and not by math. Godel's Incompleteness Theorem says some stuff about the limitations of the confidence we can place in the truth of mathematics.

Comment: what will happen if this ensembles of number's if it's exist, is it a prefered then primes ensembles ?

Comment: I have no idea what youre talking about. I dont think youre structuring your sentences very well.  Without knowing if such a number exists, I cannot (and frankly will not) deduce what properties it might have.

Comment: If “$a$ is divisible by $b$” is defined by “there exists $c$ such that $a=bc$”, then of course $0$ is divisible by $0$. Which doesn't mean the division of $0$ by $0$ is defined; it's a common misunderstanding believing that “$a$ is divisible by $b$” means “$a/b$ exists”.

Comment: it's seems to me that if this numbers existe then will be have a great place in pure mathematics then the primes number's .

Comment: @Berci, Thank you for your answer , but when you said me that i can't find a very general proof Then this ensembles of numbers that i cited probably exist .